# What is admin_devel module in drupal?

Tags: debugging

THis module is separate from the devel module that gives ability to dpm() variables etc. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`admin_devel` is part of [Administration Menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) and provides administration and debugging functionality for site builders. It's quite a small module; in Drupal 7 it only has a function to rebuild all system menu links. It isn't tied to Devel in any particular way.

Comment: Just to say, rooby's answer is more comprehensive - there is also a javascript debugging function :)

Comment: Mine was also first, but you can't win 'em all :)

Answer (score 5):

The admin_devel module actually comes with the [admin_menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module.

It adds a debug function for javascript debugging (along the lines of dpm for php), which you can include and use.

It also adds a button you can press to rebuild system links, which is on the admin menu settings page.

This rebuilds menu item links that are handled by the drupal core system module.